# Turing images into greyscale or transparent in ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have an image that I want to use as a background. Before using it as background, I'd like to turn the image into grayscale or even make it transparent in ReactJS. How do I do that in ReactJS.

My code looks like this at the moment:

```
        <GridListTile>
          <img
            style={{ -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%) }}
            src={image.urls.regular}
            alt={image.alt_description}
          />
        </GridListTile>
```

I've tried using `-webkit-filter: grayscale(100%)` and `filter` with no luck.

Comment: If you want ```-webkit-filter``` then use this like ```style={{WebkitFilter: 'grayscale(100%)'}}```

Comment: It's better off using `background-url` instead of the `img` tag in a situation like yours.

Comment: @Hit-or-miss I can't use background image for this case as my scenario is I have GridList of images (these images can change), so I need to dynamically change the grayscale

Comment: you can simply use filter, but put grayscale inside a string (you can use template strings to change the grayscale dinamically) - check my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add `style={{ filter: "grayscale(100%)" }}` instead. Here's a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/confident-sea-bhi6d

```
<img
  style={{ filter: "grayscale(100%)" }}
  src={image.urls.regular}
  alt={image.alt_description}
/>
```